# Select tag closing on releasing click - Angular

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I have an angular component with a select tag inside a dropdown menu to be used as a filter for the table using bootstrap. The problem is the dropdown closes as soon as i open the select tag's drop down to select a value instead of keeping the dropdown open to click on the filter button.

```
            <th>Start Time <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-filter filter-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div class="container p-0" style="width:50%;">
                        <div class="col-12 pr-0 pl-0 mb-3">Show items with value that:</div>
                        <select class="p-1 mb-3">
                                <option value="after">After</option>
                                <option value="before">Before</option>
                                <option value="equal">Equal</option>
                            </select>
                        <input type="date" class="p-1 m-2">
                        <select class="p-1 m-2">
                                <option value="and" style="width: 10px;">AND</option>
                                <option value="or">OR</option>    
                            </select>
                        <select class="p-1 mb-3">
                                <option value="after">After</option>
                                <option value="before">Before</option>
                                <option value="equal">Equal</option>
                            </select>
                        <input type="date" class="p-1 m-2">

                        <div class="row">
                            <button class="col-5 btn btn-primary p2 m-2">Filter</button>
                            <button class="col-5 btn btn-primary p2 m-2">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </th>
```

I'm using angular 6 for the application and have bootstrap included for styling.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a link of the code ?

Comment: **Confused!**  Please understand Dropdown and select tag are same.

Comment: could you please provide a working example!

Comment: Have you noticed? Your prompted box is closing not the drop-down. So try to fix that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the workarounds for that is wrapping the content of the `dropdown-menu` inside a form tag like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <form>
    <div class="container p-0" style="width:50%;">
        <div class="col-12 pr-0 pl-0 mb-3">Show items with value that:</div>
        <select class="p-1 mb-3">
                <option value="after">After</option>
                <option value="before">Before</option>
                <option value="equal">Equal</option>
            </select>
        <input type="date" class="p-1 m-2">
        <select class="p-1 m-2">
                <option value="and" style="width: 10px;">AND</option>
                <option value="or">OR</option>    
            </select>
        <select class="p-1 mb-3">
                <option value="after">After</option>
                <option value="before">Before</option>
                <option value="equal">Equal</option>
            </select>
        <input type="date" class="p-1 m-2">

        <div class="row">
            <button class="col-5 btn btn-primary p2 m-2">Filter</button>
            <button class="col-5 btn btn-primary p2 m-2">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @nadhir. Worked like a charm. But now, I'm unable to access the value selected from the dropdown. ngModel returns undefined

Comment: @UjjwalSharma oh that's a different issue, but based on the code you provided, I don't see ngModel in your html

Comment: @UjjwalSharma can you please mark this answer as correct since it solved your initial issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on the initial dropdown (when you click on **State** it opens)